# como llenar un select con otro selct desde ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, select

Hola comunidad me encuentro con el siguiente problema, nececito llenar un `select` con otro **select** desde **ajax**.

me explico: tengo un select de esta forma en mi archimo **html**

```
 <div class="form-group mt-1">
  <select class="form-control mt-1" id="frutas">
       <option value="manzana">manzana</option>
       <option value="uva">uva</option>
       <option value="pera">pera</option>
      </select>
 </div>

   <div class="form-group mt-1">
        <!--este select es el que nececito llenar segun la fruta-->
      <select class="form-control mt-1" id="clave-frutas">
      </select>
 </div>
```

lo que yo nececito es reemplasar solo los `options`  desde ana llamada a **ajax** , por ejemplo estoy intentando hacer lo siguinte...

archivo **JS**

```
$('#frutas').change(function(){

    var category=$(this).val();
    var url="ajax/select_category.php";

         $.ajax({

           url:url,
           type:"POST",
           data:{category:category}

         }).done(function(data){

               $("#clave-fruta").html(data);
         })    
     })
```

y en mi archivo **select_category.php** tengo lo siguiente..

```
<?php

 $category=$_POST["category"];

 if ($category=="pera"){ ?>

     <option value="granada">granada</option>
     <option value="metralleta">metralleta</option>
     <option value="pistola">pistola</option>

  <?php }elseif($category=="manzana"){?>

      <option value="cervesa">cervesa</option>
      <option value="vino">vino</option>
      <option value="champaña">champaña</option>

 <?php }elseif($category=="uva"){?>

      <option value="informatica">informatica</option>
      <option value="programacion">programacion</option>
      <option value="diseño">diseño</option>


 }   ?>
```

a la hora de el ajax devolver esos **options** los tira fuera de el select es decir yo espero un input tipo `select` normal,  pero me tira los options fuera como si fueran texto plano y se ven asi por ejepmlo si eligo **manzana**

```
          cervesa
          vino 
          champaña
```

[image: imagen del resultado]

como podria lograr lo que nececito alguna soluccion que estoy hacindo mal? gracias de ante mano

Comment: No veo que estes retornando nada.  Debes de retornar un string con el HTML de las opciones.

Comment: a que te refieres exactamente? por que si esta retornando los options solo que no dentro de la etiqueta `select`

Answer (score 2):

Mira lo modifique un poco, pero hay lo tienes funcionando, espero y te sirva.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="form-group mt-1">
   <select class="form-control mt-1" id="frutas">
        <option value="manzana">manzana</option>
        <option value="uva">uva</option>
        <option value="pera">pera</option>
   </select>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group mt-1">
         <!--este select es el que nececito llenar segun la fruta-->
       <select class="form-control mt-1" id="clave-frutas">
       </select>

       <div id="resul"></div>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#frutas').on('change',function(){
  
    var category=$("#frutas").val();
    var url="select_category.php";

         $.ajax({

           url:url,
           type:"POST",
           data:{category:category}

         }).done(function(data){

               $("#clave-frutas").html(data);
         })    
     });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**select_category.php**

```html
<?php

 $category=$_POST["category"];

 if ($category=="pera"){ ?>

     <option value="granada">granada</option>
     <option value="metralleta">metralleta</option>
     <option value="pistola">pistola</option>

  <?php }elseif($category=="manzana"){?>

      <option value="cervesa">cervesa</option>
      <option value="vino">vino</option>
      <option value="champaña">champaña</option>

 <?php }elseif($category=="uva"){?>

      <option value="informatica">informatica</option>
      <option value="programacion">programacion</option>
      <option value="diseño">diseño</option>

<?php
 }   

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

En php estas generando el HTML directamente sin retornar nada.  Debes retornar un string que contenga el HTML que deseas.  Algo asi:

```
<?php

 $category=$_POST["category"];

 if ($category=="pera"){ 

     echo '<option value="granada">granada</option>
     <option value="metralleta">metralleta</option>
     <option value="pistola">pistola</option>';

  } elseif ($category=="manzana"){

      echo '<option value="cervesa">cervesa</option>
      <option value="vino">vino</option>
      <option value="champaña">champaña</option>';

 } elseif ($category=="uva"){

      echo '<option value="informatica">informatica</option>
      <option value="programacion">programacion</option>
      <option value="diseño">diseño</option>';


 }   ?>
```

Comment: pues no me funciono da el mismo resultado basicamnete hisiste lo mismo solo que agregaste echo

Answer (score 0):

tu código no es muy entendible..

Este es un ejemplo, en la que te puedas basar para llenar un select.
en tu html

```
<select id="dropdown"></select>
```

En tu archvo javascript..

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlPath, // "ajax/select_category.php";
            success: function(data)
            {
                helpers.buildDropdown(
                    jQuery.parseJSON(data),
                    $('#dropdown'),
                    'Select an option'
                );
            }
        });
```

EN TU ARCHIVO PHP el que responde la peticion, ajax. deberia debolver un json.. con la siguiente estructura

```
 {
     key:value
 }
```

en este caso.. te pongo un arreglo de objetos..

```
[

    {"id":1,"name":"Option 1"},

    {"id":2,"name":"Option 2"},

    {"id":3,"name":"Option 3"},

    {"id":4,"name":"Option 4"},

    {"id":5,"name":"Option 5"},

]
```

si te fijaste en la peticion ajax, cuando esta es exitosa. llama un helper.. llamada buildDropdow.. este es el codigo..

```
var helpers =

{

    buildDropdown: function(result, dropdown, emptyMessage)

    {

        // Remove current options

        dropdown.html('');

        // Add the empty option with the empty message

        dropdown.append('<option value="">' + emptyMessage + '</option>');

        // Check result isnt empty

        if(result != '')

        {

            // Loop through each of the results and append the option to the dropdown

            $.each(result, function(k, v) {

                dropdown.append('<option value="' + v.id + '">' + v.name + '</option>');

            });

        }

    }

}
```

que se encarga de construirla..

en tu caso el select_category.php deberia debolver un array..

que al ser parseado en json..

devuelve los datos como se espetan.. en un json..

```
if($category=="manzana")
  $arr = array( value => 'Cerveza', value => 'Vino', value => 'Champaña');

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Espero haberte ilustrado...

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo estas funciones y me sirven para cualquier combo:

```
function llenarCmb(combo, datos) {
    combo.find('option').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "-1") {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
        combo.append("<option value='" + datos[i]["id"] + "'>" + datos[i]["nombre"] + "</option>");
    }
    combo.selectric("refresh");//Esta linea quitala, solo sirve si tus combos son selectric
}
function llenarCombo(name, rutaControlador, strAccion, funcAppendCombo, id_cmb_padre) {
    $("select[name=" + name + "]").each(function () {
        combo = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: rutaControlador,
            data: { accion: strAccion, id_padre: id_cmb_padre },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (datos) {
                funcAppendCombo(combo, datos);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //console.log(jqXHR);
                alert("No se pudo cargar el combo " + name + " : " + textStatus + ' Thrown: ' + errorThrown);
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
                //console.log(jqXHR);
                //alert("complete\njqXHR="+jqXHR+"\nstatus="+status);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Para llenar un combo la invoco así:

```
llenarCombo("nameDelCombo", "path/valoresJsonCombo.php", "metodoQueDevueveElJson", llenarCmb, null);
```

Si el combo a llenar tiene un combo padre la invocación es de esta manera:

```
$("#idDelComboPadre").change(function () {
    llenarCombo("nameComboHijo", "path/LlemarComboHijo.php", "listar", llenarCmb, $(this).val());
});
```

Como vez la diferencia es el ultimo parámetro, si no hay combo padre paso `null`, si existe un combo padre tienes que pasar `$(this).val()`, para invocar eso la función debe invocarse desde el evento `change` del padre.

Las funciones que tengo del lado del servidor son php y devuelven un json de id y nombre para el combo:

```
include_once("../../../../../conexion/ConexionGenerica.php");
class CatTipoDeBeca_model extends ConexionGenerica{
    public function __construct($rutaProperties){
                               parent::__construct($rutaProperties,"SQLsrv");
    }
    public function listar($parametros){
        //$sql = "select id_tipo_proveedor, tipo_prov_descr from ".$this->egresosBD.".padron.cat_tipo_proveedor where id_tipo_proveedor in ('B', 'C') " ;

        $sql = "select id_tipo_beca,ctb_descripcion from ".$this->ingresosBD.".convenios.cat_tipo_beca where estatus='AC'";

        $resultado = $this->consultarSQL($sql);
        $no_filas =  $resultado[1] ;
        $tipoDeBeca=array();
        if($no_filas>0){
            foreach ($resultado[2] as $clave => $valor) {
                $tipoDeBeca[]=array("id"=>$valor["id_tipo_beca"], "nombre" => $valor["ctb_descripcion"]);
            }
        }else{
            $tipoDeBeca[]=array("id"=>"-2", "nombre" => "No hay información en el catálogo.");
        }
        $this->cerrarConexion();
        echo json_encode($tipoDeBeca);
    }
}
```

Esta ultima parte no importa como la hagas, lo importante es que devuelvan el mismo json de pares `[{"id"="1","nombre"="uno"},{"id"="2","nombre"="dos"}]` ya que esto podria estar escrito en en java o en c# y el javascript no se ve afectado, mientras el json sea el mismo.

Por ultimo mis html son así:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
      <select id="nombreCombo" name="nombreCombo" class="selectric">
        <option value="-1">--Seleccione--</option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

También si te das cuenta en ningún momento revuelvo html, javascript o php. Tengo todo separado, revolverlo son malas practicas.